# 'go to view', 'add view' popup item menus not available in vs 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have an MVC 4 project with VS 2012. For all controllers, I do not see the menu items like 'Go to View' and 'Add View' anytime I right click on a public action method to go to the view or add a new view for that action. The same problem when I come from a view page, and try to go back to its controller by right clicking inside that view page.  Please advise.  Thank you.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped on this too...If you are within an API controller you do not get that option. For regular controllers the options were there (vs 2012 pro on win 7)

Hope this helps someone